# android and VBO use

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

There's an exotic GPU, called `Vivante GC800`, that only supports client arrays, no VBOs at all (this, BTW, was why MALI400, was considered "more compatible" with games). To me this is interesting: if you check on, say, http://dx.com, you'll see than there are a ton of android 4.1+ devices offered, that only have 512MB memory. This probably means, that the GPU shares memory with the OS. Is there then any reason left then, why one should use VBOs at all (with any GPU, under android), as it is probaby not "fast memory", as one tends to think of it?

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that 90% of Android gamers go with Samsung Galaxy…

I would assume that fairly recent editions of the latter (what gamers actually use to play their games), boast genuine graphic memory, ergo using VBOs is well worth it even assuming 90% of (Android) devices don't support it (which I doubt).
Also worth it if you consider porting your games to iOS.
Also worth it if you want your code to perform well 3 years later? 3 years isn't a very long time...

""there are a ton of android 4.1+ devices offered, that only have 512MB memory. This probably means, that the GPU shares memory with the OS""

…and that is an unverified assumption : )

Comment: it's not that much, that I think VBOs aren't supported, than that I believe, that allocating them simply takes memory from what little is left of system memory. Of course, the GC 800 is an exception, where there are not supported outright (that is, not even "emulated").

Comment: @user1095108 after loading your data into a VBO you can release it to reclaim memory on the client side, so you're not taking anything away. Your question was, "is there any reason left to use VBOs?" so I tried answering that... If using VBOs took memory 'from what little is left' that would be a reason NOT to use VBOs. However that is not true.

Comment: You forget one benefit of client arrays - the possibility of easily modifying them. So there is a downside to using VBOs if dedicated memory is not used for them. Likewise for textures, which can also reside on the client side.

Comment: Oh, and another thing, those 10% could still cover millions of players.

Comment: @user1095108 I'm not forgetting anything, maybe you should have asked 'when is it better not to use VBOs?' instead. This is a Q&A not a place for debate... Do you write OpenGL-ES code?? Do you run it on actual devices? The benefits of VBOs and when to use them or not are obvious to people that need them...

Comment: There are some things that are gleaned only after some time has passed. I've used to think: VBO is the right way, VBO has to be used whenever possible - and wrote my code that way. But this mantra turned out incorrect in some instances. I wonder if some common rule-of-thumb has emerged for the lower-end devices. Perhaps using VBOs on them is generally irrelevant. Was just wondering. One would think, that not supporting VBOs, would cause the Vivante GPU to lose its GLES certificate, but apparently it was not so.

Comment: After a long time, I've remembered what you've forgotten and that's collision detection. In order to do collision detection, the mesh needs to be retained in main memory. This means, if you don't use client arrays, that some mesh data is duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

It might me that each GPU type has it's own way of handling buffer memory, for iOS (PowerVR Series) the documentation clearly states the benefits.

Maybe to understand Android, we can take a look at the other camp:

From: [OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3ddrawing/conceptual/opengles_programmingguide/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData.html)

> This code works, but is inefficient. Each time DrawModel is called, the index and vertex data are copied to OpenGL ES, and transferred to the graphics hardware. If the vertex data does not change between invocations, these unnecessary copies can impact performance. To avoid unnecessary copies, your app should store its vertex data in a vertex buffer object (VBO). Because OpenGL ES owns the vertex buffer object’s memory, it can store the buffer in memory that is more accessible to the graphics hardware, or pre-process the data into the preferred format for the graphics hardware.

TL:DR: Check what the manufacturer of the GPU recommends.

Comment: There used to be these benchmarks for the ipod touch and iphone, where VBO vs. non-VBO code was tested. I recally the tests came out even, there was no benefit in using a VBO.